# Cricket and no ball and a shot played by batsman while running

Tags: rules, cricket

In normal circumstances, not last ball or winning stroke, a batsman plays a shot and runs for 1 run. It turned out to be a no ball. Of course, the team would get 2 runs. But will the batsman get 2 runs or just 1 run & 1 will be added to extras towards no ball? I want to read the rule.

Comment: What normally happens in scoring when No ball is signalled and awarded? Why would the batsmen running change that?

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstances, the batsman will be awarded the run he scored (in this case 1 run) and the team will be awarded x+1 runs 1 run for the no ball, x runs scored by the batsman. This same rule will be applicable if the batsman scores a boundary.